# Objective C ARC equivalent for self?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.3

What is the equivalent keyword i can use in the place of self in ARC enabled projects?
ex:- `[self mymethod];`  what is ARC equivalent of this method call?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what do you mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's still the same

```
[self myMethod];
```

But in ARC environment, IIRC, you need to do it like this: (I don't know if this is the source of your question, but when I migrated the first time to ARC, I get compile error if I'm not doing this).

```
@interface myController()
- (void)myMethod; // you need to declare the method here, if you haven't declared it on the .h
@end

@implementation

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self myMethod];
}

- (void)myMethod
{
  NSLog(@"!");
}

@end
```

hope this help

Answer (score 5):

I don't quite get it? Why ARC should have different syntax for method calls? It is an automatic memory management, where in most cases you won't need to use retain/release, nothing more. So it would look like this:

```
[self mymethod];
```

Comment: Pay attention that ARC is not a kind of Garbage Collector. It's a compiler feature! No runtime magic is involved.

Comment: I see, I actually successfully managed to not use it, like to know exactly what I release, and why, and when, so I probably missed that one. I'll correct the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In ARC(Automatic Reference Counting),you don't need to release or retain. It has nothing to do with calling methods!

ARC - Automatic Reference Counting implements automatic memory management for Objective-C objects and blocks, freeing the programmer from the need explicitly insert retains and releases. Since this is handled at compile time, no collector process is need to continually clear memory and remove unreferenced objects.

For calling a method, you still do it this way:`[self mymethod];`